# The current code I am using is not working to replace my text to other text within a .txt file, how do I replace this with Python?

Tags: python, file

**Currently using this code**

```
f1 = open('C:\Users\folderName\Python Tests\data.txt', 'r')

f2 = open('C:\Users\folderName\Python Tests\data.txt', 'w')

for line in f1:

        f2.write(line.replace('pyton', 'python'))

f1.close()

f2.close()
```

Im using Jupyter Lab and Python 3.7.5 64-bit

any help?

The issue at matter is actually for a MUCH bigger file that lives on my local computer, I have a notepad file that has about a million lines of information.

What i really need is to replace "    " with "|"

But im looking to automate this, instead of going in the file and hitting CTLR + H everytime

thanks guys

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  What data did you read?  What is it after you fix the spelling error?  What appears in the output file?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can easily read and replace specific word/letter/space etc from file with another text/space.

```
f1 = open("data.txt", "r")
text = f1.read();
f1.close()

f2 = open("data.txt", "w")
text = text.replace(" ","|")
f2.write(text);
f2.close()
```